# how to retrieve data from database into input values of a form in laravel php to complete the update action?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to populate data into input values from mysql database so that I can see and change the data.

I have a form named ***form.blade.php*** which will be included in both ***create.blade.php*** and ***edit.blade.php***.
What I need is to know is how to retrive data from database to populate data to those inputs  when I click on edit.Then when I click on ***Add button*** in ***index.blade.php*** ,I'll be redirected to ***create.blade.php*** and then inputs must be empty.

I tried to add some code functions to every input value

```
{{old('title',$page->title}}  then {{ isset($page) ? page->title: ''}}
```

but its not working

I'm using one form to perform create and update actions

This is the edit.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('content')

    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header card-header-success">
            <h4 class="card-title ">Pages Data Table</h4>
            <p class="card-category"> Here you can update Page data</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">

            {!! Form::open(['action' => 'PagesController@store', 'method' => 'POST' ]) !!}
                @csrf
                @method('PUT')
                @include('pages.includes.form')
            {!! Form::close() !!}
    </div>
    </div>


@endsection
```

and this is the child form form.blade.php

```
    <div class="form-group">
        {{Form::label('title', 'Title')}}

  {{ Form::text('title', '',['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Title']) }}

    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{Form::label('content', 'Content')}}
        <br>
        {{ Form::textarea('content', '',['class' =>'form-control', 'placeholder'=> 'Content']) }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-check form-check-radio">
                    <label class="form-check-label">
                            {{Form::input('radio','status', '0',['class' => 'form-check-input','checked'=>'checked'])}} Status Off
                        <span class="circle">
                            <span class="check"></span>
                        </span>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check form-check-radio">
                    <label class="form-check-label">
                            {{Form::input('radio','status', '1',['class' => 'form-check-input'])}} Status On
                        <span class="circle">
                            <span class="check"></span>
                        </span>
                    </label>
                </div>

    </div>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Save">
```

Comment: Using Form facade from Laravel Collective already inserts CSRF into the form. ;)

Comment: so I don't need to add @csrf ?

Comment: Sorry, that's not your main issue here. But no, you don't.

Comment: This should work: `{{old('title') ?? $page->title }}`  | or: You missed the `$` in here: `{{ isset($page) ? $page->title : ''}}`

Comment: syntax error, unexpected 'title' (T_STRING), expecting ')'  >>the input:
`{{ Form::text('title', '{{old('title') ?? $page->title }}'  ,['class' => 'form-control' , 'placeholder' => 'Title']) }}`

Answer (score 0):

When you are using the same form for create and update, you can use the **optional** method.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('date') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="date" id="date" value="{{ old('date', optional($expense)->date) }}">
```

In the create function send the variable as null like `$expense = null;`
And in edit function the variable has its own value from database. So when the variable has its value the input field will be filled by value from database otherwise it will be empty.

Comment: I'm getting an Error > how can I put it in this html input?
```{{ Form::text('title', '',['class' => 'form-control' , 'placeholder' => 'Title']) }}'''